# How to group on PHP MySQL JOIN results?

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, group-concat

**Expected result:**

```
Berries: blueberry, raspberry, strawberry
Citrus: grapefruit, lime
Pear
```

---

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fruits` (
  `id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fruits` (`id`, `group`, `name`) VALUES
('03E7', '', 'Berries'),
('0618', '03E7', 'blueberry'),
('051B', '03E7', 'raspberry'),
('02AA', '03E7', 'strawberry'),
('035F', '', 'Citrus'),
('07A5', '035F', 'grapefruit'),
('0633', '035F', 'lime'),
('05E1', '', 'Pear');
```

Current PHP:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.name as `group`, b.name as name FROM fruits a LEFT JOIN fruits b ON b.`group` = a.id WHERE a.`group` = ''");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['group'] . ': ' . $row['name'] . "\n";        
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
}

?>
```

Current result:

```
Berries: blueberry
Berries: raspberry
Berries: strawberry
Citrus: grapefruit
Citrus: lime
Pear:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ExplosionPills discovering me about MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` I have updated my snippet that returns the expected result:

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.name as `group`, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.name SEPARATOR ', ') as name FROM fruits a LEFT JOIN fruits b ON b.`group` = a.id WHERE a.`group` = '' GROUP BY a.name");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $group = $row['group'];
        $name  = $row['name'];

        if (isset($name)) {
            echo $group . ': ' . $name . "\n";
        } else  {
            echo $group . "\n";
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
}

?>
```

SQL result:

> Showing rows 0 - 2 ( 3 total, Query took 0.0004 sec).

```
group   | name
--------+--------
Berries | blueberry, raspberry, strawberry
Citrus  | grapefruit, lime
Pear    | NULL
```

PHP result:

```
Berries: blueberry, raspberry, strawberry
Citrus: grapefruit, lime
Pear
```

Everyone is welcome for any better implement with better improvement?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) ... WHERE a.group = '' GROUP BY a.name
```

In summary, you need a `GROUP BY` clause, and the grouped column needs to be aggregated in some way (otherwise you will get only one value).  If this doesn't work, you can easily do it in PHP code with the results you got:

```
$fruits = array();
while ($row = fetch($query)) {
   //Can be skipped, but you will get notices
   if (!isset($fruits[$row['group']]) {
      $fruits[$row['group']] = array();
   }
   $fruits[$row['group']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: default SEPARATOR is ',' whitout a space, you way want to change it to GROUP_CONCAT(b.name SEPARATOR ', ')

Comment: Thanks @ExplosionPills for discovering me `GROUP_CONCAT`! Your snippet does not work, there are no such a PHP function `fetch` and why would I need for `array`. I just added my answer with working example.
@PugganSe, thanks for posting about `SEPARATOR`!

Comment: `fetch` was shorthand .. you should use a little creativity to extrapolate what you need out of your answer..